# Featured post on Sharepoint main page

Tags: blog

Is there a way to feature a blog post on the main page of a SharePoint 2010 blog site by keeping it above the most recent post?

I know you can create a sticky post for the manage post section, but I can't do something similar for the main blog page.

Thank you,